# Is there any problem with import skimage.feature?

Tags: scikit-image

I am trying to do image processing with scikit-image (version 0.16.2).  I have several issues with importing packages.  For instance, even straightforward packages like skimage.feature cannot be imported.  Is there something I need to do to get this working?

Comment: Do you still get the error after updating to the latest version of skimage ?

Comment: Yes, I do get errors with the latest version of skimage.  Even basic modules like skimage.feature cannot be imported.  Have no idea what is happening?  Perhaps will switch back to OpenCV.

Comment: It souds like a problem of your environment, do you see skimage documentation by running ```help('skimage')``` in Python ?

Comment: I resolved the issue by uninstalling and reinstalling skimage.  No idea why/how the issue was resolved.